# Download and save static images in phone

Tags: android, image, download

In my application when i query a http URL i get list of object, some times these object needs to be rendered on listview and sometimes in my custom view.

Each of the object which i receive from server has image tag, most of the time images are always constant i.e same image URL only.

I just want to download the images once, & also my app should have to download once in a while when the images got changed in server. What is the best way?

I know like, we need to perform operation in thread, but not getting the exact idea of how to do?. how to check for change of image & efficient way of storing them. Any hint

Answer (score 0):

For storage, I recommend Internal Storage 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

And for downloading
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can create a AsyncTask where you pass a ImageView, where you want to show the img, with the url as a tag. And check in the internal storage if you have that img already saved if not just download it.